# Partitioned Collection paritionkey

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I´m confused what to choose for PartitionKey and what effect it has. If I use Partitioned Collection then I must define a Partition Key that can be used by DocumentDB to distribute the data among multiple servers. But lets say that I choose a partitionKey that is always the same for all documents. Will I still be able to get up to 250k RU/s for a single Partitioned Collection?

In my case the main query is get all documents with paging but in a timeline (newest first)

```
SELECT TOP 10 c.id, c.someValue, u.id FROM c
JOIN u IN c.users ORDER BY c.createdDate DESC
```

A minified version of the document looks like this

```
    {
     id: "1", 
     someValue: "Foo"
     createdDate: "2016-14-4-14:38:00.00"
     //Max 100 users
     users: [{id: "1", id: "2"}]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to have multiple distinct partition key values in order to achieve high throughput levels in DocumentDB.

A partition in DocumentDB supports up to 10,000 RU/s, so you need at least 25* distinct partition key values to reach 250 RU/s. DocumentDB divides the partition keys evenly across the available partitions, i.e. a partition might contain documents with multiple partition keys, but the data for a partition key is guaranteed to stay within a single partition. You must also structure your workload in a manner that distributes reads/writes across these partition keys.

**You may need a slightly higher number of partition keys than 25 (50-100) in practice since some of the partition keys might hash to the same partition*

Answer (score 0):

So, we have a partitioned (10 partitions) collection with a throughput of 10000 RU/s. Partition Key is CountryCode and we only have data for 5 countries. Data for **two countries** were hashed into the **same physical partition**. As per documentation found in the following link, we were expecting data to be reorganized to the empty partitions once the 10GB limit was hit for the said partition. That didn't happen and we could no longer add data for those two countries.

Obviously, the right thing to do would be to choose a partition key that ensures low cardinality, but the documentation is misleading.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

*When a physical partition p reaches its storage limit, Cosmos DB seamlessly splits p into two new partitions p1 and p2 and distributes values corresponding to roughly half the keys to each of the partitions. This split operation is invisible to your application.*